# Create exceptions in htaccess

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, routes

So I was trying to load this project using .htaccess to redirect to webroot

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule ^$ Webroot/ [L]
    RewriteRule (.*) Webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Now in that webroot folder I want everything to load on the index.php which required another htaccess in the web rooot folder

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [PT,L]
</IfModule>
```

The question is I want to make an exception that if the route is {url}/public, it can/should load files or images from there.

Comment: have mod_rewrite  working on server or tried this  ? RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?example.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/subdirectory/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /subdirectory/$1
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?example.com$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ subdirectory/index.html [L]       Change  subdirectory to your directory

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?example.com$ 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/subdirectory/ 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /subdirectory/$1 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?example.com$ 
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ subdirectory/index.html [L]
```

Change sub-directory to your directory